# Tracing a site's redirects

Tags: javascript, html, request

I'm trying to request a link from a homepage, say www.example.com. I've tried putting example.com as a referer in the header, but I still get a "seems like you've been redirected from the wrong page" error when I request the link. Could this be that there are intermediary javascript requests? How would I trace the request path?

Comment: What do you mean by "request a link"? How do you know which domain the URL expects the referer to be (and what makes you think  example.com might be the right one?)

Comment: I meant send a request to the link, like open/follow it. I don't know what domain the URL expects the referer to be-- that's my problem.

Comment: There may well be no way to tell from the outside if the site is using this mechanism for protecting content.